# Redirect http://example.com/foo to http://example.com/#foo

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm having a lot of trouble working out how to use mod_rewrite (via htaccess) to do the following redirect:

http://example.com/foo to http://example.com/#foo

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Ok, think I've got it:

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ http://site.com/#$1 [R,NE,NC]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ site.com/#$1 [R,NE,NC]
```